# how to get the dx and dy of a line in spritekit swift

Tags: swift, math, sprite-kit

I have a ball, and I want to make it move in a direction by applying a force.
In my game, I have the 2 points that form a line that I want the ball to follow.

How can I know the vector components `dx` and `dy`?

I only know the (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

EDIT ::

```
let ddx = (bullet.position.x - position.x)
let ddy = (bullet.position.y - position.y)
let Len = sqrt((ddx * ddx) + (ddy * ddy))
let dx = ddx / Len
let dy = ddy / Len
let force = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
let action = SKAction.applyForce(force, at: position, duration: 2)
let fire = SKAction.repeatForever(action)
bullet.run(fire, withKey: "firing\(bullet.name)")
```

still nothing happens

update ::

It worked by this

```
let action = SKAction.moveBy(x: bullet.position.x, y: bullet.position.y, duration: 2)
```

Comment: In the code you posted where you said "nothing happens" you aren't actually telling anything to run the action.

Comment: edited i just forgot to add it

Comment: You'll need to apply a greater force to the bullet. Try this `let force = CGVector(dx: 100 * dx, dy: 100 * dy)`.

Comment: it worked thank you , voted

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need components of unit direction vector:

```
ddx = (x2 - x1)
ddy = (y2 - y1)
Len = Sqrt(ddx * ddx + ddy * ddy)
dx = ddx / Len
dy = ddy / Len
```